# web.config error when trying to display an image

Tags: asp.net, web-config, iis-7.5

I ran into an interesting error when trying to load an image and I was wondering if anyone else has experienced this or even better know how to fix it.

So I have a virtual Directory setup through IIS 7.5 referencing a network share.  I am using valid credentials and have verified that I can connect to the share using these credentials.

When I try to navigate to the image I get the following error:

```
 Parser Error Message: An error occurred loading a configuration file: Invalid file name for file monitoring: '\\share2\EmployeePhoneListPhotos$\web.config'. Common reasons for failure include:
    - The filename is not a valid Win32 file name.
    - The filename is not an absolute path.
    - The filename contains wildcard characters.
    - The file specified is a directory.
    - Access denied.
```

Now there is NO web.config file in this share folder, however it's just displaying a .jpg image from here so there should be no need for one.

Does anyone have any idea why it would even look for a web.config file in a folder that only had images?

Comment: Is the dollar causing the problem (hidden share)?

Comment: no because it is using the same thing on our production side in the old site and it works fine however in developement when I map the virtual folder it throws an exception.